# How to query YQL rss table by pubDate

Tags: yql, pubdate

I would like to get yahoo finance news for last 3 days, something like that

```
select * from rss where url='http://finance.yahoo.com.news/rss' and pubDate >= '2012-06-23'
```

BUT this part "pubDate >= '2012-06-23'" is ignored. I always get the same results with or without this clause.
What is the right syntax to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Irina,
you're using a 'greater than' operator over a string,
to filter by pubDate you'll have to use something like,

```
and pubDate >= date_trunc('month',current_date)
order by pubdate desc;
```

Comment: This does not work for me. Always get an error: "Only literals supported as RHS, found: com.yahoo.platforms.yql.Expression$FunctionExpression@21d43a5b expecting literal"

Comment: Is the url correct? Trying the url in the browser gives a 404. I suspect its 'http://finance.yahoo.com/news/rss

Answer (score 0):

The right query would be

```
select * from rss where url='http://finance.yahoo.com/news/rss' and item.pubDate>='2012-06-26'
```

Notice the item.pubDate. The reason for item. is because in the xml structure, pubDate is a child of item.

Unfortunately, this is not going to work for your use case (sort by time). That's because the pubDate returned is not in unix timestamp. Sorry I do not know what needs to be done in order for you to get the right results but atleast I could give you the right query :)

Comment: That's why a function like date_trunc is your best friend here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I try it in YQL Console like this:

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I try it in YQL Console like this:  select *  from rss where url='http://finance.yahoo.com/news/rss'  and item.pubDate>='2012-06-26' | sort(field="pubDate", descending="true")   and it still return all of them.   I understand that is because pubDate is a string but could not find how to convert it to datetime type in YQL Console.   Function date_trunc() does not work in this query too, I get error listed below about "expecting literal".

Comment: I found the way as using "like" operator  select * from rss where url='http://finance.yahoo.com/news/rss' and (pubDate like 'Mon, 25%' or pubDate like 'Tue, 26%')| sort(field="pubDate", descending="true").  BUT looking for something simpler.